# ADB display density revert back after reboot?

Tags: android, adb

I was trying to change the display density on my Galaxy Grand Neo using adb
It's on android 4.2.2

I used

> adb shell am display-density 200

It worked well but after rebooting the density gets back to normal . how to solve this problem please?

Or is there any way to restart **Systemui** ??

PS: my phone isn't rooted

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it through adb is only temporary. To make the change persist you need to change it in build.prop which requires root.

Assuming this is a programming question (testing purposes, which is the intended usage for that command).